# Java animate car along list of points

Tags: java

I'm trying to let a car image follow a list of points. In the current situation the car just "jumps" to the next point in the list every two seconds. How can I move the car smooth and with constant speed along the points in the list? And also how to let the car make turns? I'm thinking of hardcoding the turns but I dont know to do this and how to add it to the update method?

Update method in car class.

```
   public void update(){

    repaint();
    if(counter < Lane.firstLane.size()){
             carPosition.x = Lane.firstLane.get(counter).x;
             carPosition.y= Lane.firstLane.get(counter).y;
             System.out.println("Pos: "+getCarPosition());
             counter++;
     }
    else{
        System.out.println("Destination reached");
    }

    repaint();    

    }
```

Thread to move the car:

```
public void moveCar() {
    Runnable helloRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


           car.update();
           repaint();


        }
    };

    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(helloRunnable, 0, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Lane class:

```
public class Lane {

         public static List<Point> firstLane = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Point(10,135),new Point(124,190),new Point(363,190),new Point(469,210)));

}
```

Comment: This is a math question. Do you understand that math at hand? Could you write out formulaically a car's position at time t?

Comment: @Kon I don't know which math to use and how to use it, can you help?

Comment: You will need to *interpolate* between your points.

Comment: @Sybren The math required to do this is beyond the scope of a simple forum question. You'll need to learn the basics yourself, make some implementation, then come back. The math here is relatively simple depending on how you want to do it.

Comment: I will look at interpolation and return if it doesn't work, someone who can help with the turns part?